# iOS CloudKit is slow on querying heavy CKAsset (even with QoS)

Tags: swift, cloudkit, coreml

I am using CloudKit to download CoreML (machine learning) models. They are about 90MB each. I have the public database and default zone with one custom 'ML' record type. 
I query this 'ML' by id, and it takes more than a minute to get a response on the completion block (it should be a matter of seconds). I've tried production environment, setting quality of service, and different ways of querying with the same result (very slow).
I wonder if I'm missing something or if there is any other way of downloading the ML models that is faster?

Here's my current code:

```
let arrayPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "ML", predicate: arrayPredicate)


let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
queryOperation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
queryOperation.resultsLimit = 1
queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
  // This gets called +60 sec after
}

queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { record, error in
  // Same here
}

publicDB.add(queryOperation)
```

Comment: Why do you expect to download a 90MB blob from CloudKit to be "a matter of seconds"?

Comment: Because if I download the same file (for example) from Dropbox it takes about 5 seconds

Comment: I'm assuming your "Dropbox" test download is using a specific file known to you at the time, rather than a predicate as you're using here. If you download a specific hardcoded example without the predicate is there a speed improvement?

Comment: Is it possible to hardcode without a predicate? That’s one thing I haven’t tried, to somehow get the url of the file in iCloud and put it inside the app... It should be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched to Firebase Storage to test and the result was slightly faster, but not much faster. `rmdaddy` and `TommyBs` were right on their line of thought: CloudKit might be a bit slower because you need to query a record, but the download is on a similar speed.

My final solution was so use `Firebase Storage` as it's easy to handle download progress and then show it on UI for the user to wait.